# Python Pass multiple variables through command to change multiple lines in a text file with regex

Tags: python-2.7

Using Python 2.7 with windows 7.

File before execution:

```
build=\\server\build
apps=\\server\aps
logs=\\server\logs
```

Execute the command:

```
python test1.py \\serverbuild\loc \\serverapps\loc \\serverlogs\logs
```

test.py Contents:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import shutil

buildpath = sys.argv[1]
buildpath = buildpath.replace('\\', '\\\\')
appspath = sys.argv[2]
appspath = appspath .replace('\\', '\\\\')
logspath = sys.argv[3]
logspath = logspath .replace('\\', '\\\\')

tf = open('tmp', 'a+')

with open('test1.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        build = re.sub ('build='r'.*','build='+buildpath,line)
        tf.write(build)
        apps = re.sub ('apps='r'.*','apps='+appspath,line)
        tf.write(apps)
        logs = re.sub ('logs='r'.*','logs='+logspath,line)
        tf.write(logs)

tf.close()
f.close()
shutil.copy('tmp', 'test1.txt')
os.remove('tmp')
exit()
```

Current output after executing command:

```
build=\\serverbuild\loc
build=\\server\build
build=\\server\build
apps=\\server\aps
apps=\\serverbuild\loc
apps=\\server\aps
logs=\\server\logslogs=\\server\logslogs=\\serverbuild\loc
```

Desired output after executing command:

```
build=\\serverbuild\loc
apps=\\serverapps\loc
logs=\\serverlogs\logs
```

Can anyone help me get the desired output? I'm new to python and programming, and I need help with this. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the for loop with the following code and it worked:

```
with open('test1.txt') as f:
    line1 = f.readline()
    line2 = f.readline()
    line3 = f.readline()
    build = re.sub ('build='r'.*','build='+buildpath,line1)
    apps = re.sub ('apps='r'.*','apps='+appspath,line2)
    logs = re.sub ('logs='r'.*','logs='+logspath,line3)
    tf.write(build + apps + logs)
```